# How to delete an image from datalist from a local folder with asp.net - Error (system.io.directorynotfoundexception could not find a part of the path)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Appreciate your help with this code, I simply want to add a delete button with C# to remove an image from dataList, I'm new to this and I don't know where to go, this is the code.

```html
        <asp:DataList ID="imgList"  repeatColumns="3" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="681px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/images/{0}") %>' width="200px" Height="200px" />
                <asp:Button Text="Delete"  id="deleteButton" runat="server"  OnClick="Delete_Command" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        
        
   
     --------------------------------
       protected void Delete_Command (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string fileName = e.CommandArgument.ToString();


            File.Delete(Server.MapPath(fileName));

            FileInfo fInfo;

            fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
                         fInfo.Delete();

            imgList.DataBind();
            }
```

the issue has been solved with the help of John, now I have another issue I appreciate any help with it as well

```html
        <asp:DataList ID="imgList"  repeatColumns="3" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="681px">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/images/{0}") %>' width="200px" Height="200px" />
                <asp:Button Text="Delete" ID="deleteButton"  OnCommand="Unnamed1_Command" commandArgument='<%# Bind("Name", "~/images/{0}") %>'  runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>




        protected void Unnamed1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            File.Delete(Server.MapPath(fileName));

            FileInfo fInfo;

            fInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);
            fInfo.Delete();

            imgList.DataBind();
        }
```

I face the error system.io.directorynotfoundexception could not find a part of the path at "  fInfo.Delete();" I have no idea why, I tried a few solutions online but nothing works so far with me.

Comment: I think your asp:button needs to be an asp:CommandButton and there are attributes for that you will need to set using the <%# Bind(...) %> as you did for your img control.

Comment: That indeed worked, thanks. John but I got another error with fInfo.Delete(); it says system.io.directorynotfoundexception could not find a part of the path,, any solutoin for this please ?

Comment: That error message generally includes the path it tried to use. Go through the path one directory at a time and ensure that every node is correctly represented within the path the application is trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after multiple times of checking and code is finally working, I will share, if anyone has something to add to make it better, please do write it down:

```html
 protected void Unnamed1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
     
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo (Server.MapPath(e.CommandArgument.ToString()));
            fInfo.Delete();

            imgList.DataBind();
        }
        
        
        
         <asp:DataList ID="imgList"  repeatColumns="3" runat="server" CssClass="auto-style1" Width="681px">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/images/{0}") %>' width="200px" Height="200px" />
                <asp:Button Text="Delete" ID="deleteButton"  OnCommand="Unnamed1_Command" commandArgument='<%# Bind("Name", "~/images/{0}") %>'  runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```